# Is it possible to remove embedded fonts in PDF and use them from Servers like in Webpages?

Tags: perl, pdflib

The fonts associated with any text inside PDF files are embedded to PDF file causing the file size to increase considerably.

Is it possible to remove all those embedded fonts from a PDF file to reduce the file size? Instead, I want to use fonts from the local machine or from a specific location. Can I achieve this with either **Compart DBMill or PDFLib or Perl**?

Rasterizing the text is not an option since it would make the text inaccessible.

Comment: To clarify: You want a PDF without a font embedded and force the consumer to already have the font in order to properly view the PDF. You do not want to remove an embedded font to steal it and use it somewhere else.

Comment: related: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/442685

Comment: :-)Yes. This requirement is for an internal purpose and the fonts available are already in the servers. The users are also going to be inside the server network. The PDF file pages spans to 1000s and has quite a large number of fonts embedded making it weigh more. I'm not sure if it is possible at all in the first place. But would be cool if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [CAM::PDF](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF) can do that. It has a deEmbedFont method that removes references to a font, and [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CAM::PDF#doc-deEmbedFont-pagenum-fontname) says you should use `cleanse` afterwards to gain a size benefit.

> Removes embedded font data, leaving font reference intact. Returns true if the font exists and 1) font is not embedded or 2) embedded data was successfully discarded. Returns false if the font does not exist, or the embedded data could not be discarded.
>
> The optional $basefont parameter allows you to change the font. This is useful when some applications embed a standard font (see below) and give it a funny name, like SYLXNP+Helvetica. In this example, it's important to change the basename back to the standard Helvetica when de-embedding.
>
> De-embedding the font does NOT remove it from the PDF document, it just removes references to it. To get a size reduction by throwing away unused font data, you should use the following code sometime after this method.
>
> ```
> $self->cleanse();
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion Simbabque. I will try this and will post the results here.

Comment: Does this even work? I got it to return true but the saved output (no matter if I use `output` or `cleanoutput`) still contains the fonts… @parapente what did your tests give? → reported as https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=148408

Comment: @mirabilos that's a while ago. I can't remember, sorry. And I don't have the means to test this now.